# print elements of one array based on values set in another array

Tags: c, arrays, optimization

I have two arrays, one is data[n] array which is of type int and stores random values. The other is result[n/4] array, which has details about 4 integers of 'data' array in one element.

For example : result[0]=1000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 implies that data[0], data[1], data[3] are needed to be printed out. simillarly result[1] has details about data[4] to data[7] in each byte of it and hence if 'n' elements are present in data array, n/4 elements are present in result array.

Now I am provided with result and data arrays and also the count value(no. of elements in result array) and I have to print those 'data' values for which 'result' value is set(i.e., '1000 0000'). I have tried two methods.

Method 1:

```
i=0;j=0;
while(i<count) 
{
if((result[i]>>24 & 0xff) > 0) printf("%d",data[j]);
if((result[i]>>16 & 0xff) > 0) printf("%d",data[j+1]);
if((result[i]>>8 & 0xff) > 0) printf("%d",data[j+2]);
if((result[i]>>0 & 0xff) > 0) printf("%d",data[j+3]);
i++;
j+=4;
}
```

Method 2 :

```
while(i<count){
    if((res[i] & 0x80000000)==0x80000000)  printf("%d\n",dat[x]); 
    if((res[i] & 0x00800000)==0x00800000)  printf("%d\n",dat[x+1]); 
    if((res[i] & 0x00008000)==0x80008000)  printf("%d\n",dat[x+2]); 
    if((res[i] & 0x80000080)==0x80000080)  printf("%d\n",dat[x+3]); 
    i++;
    x+=4;
}
```

I am not satisfied with performance of first method so eliminated shift operator from my code and went to second one. There is considerable improvement in speed, but this improved speed also is not enough for my application. 
Suggest any other techniques to solve my problem in faster way than that of stated two methods.

Comment: `if((res[i] & 0x80000000)==0x80000000)` ie equal to write a faster `if(res[i] & 0x80000000)`. I think that the bottlneck here is the printf. Think to store values in a third array and print it at the end of while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bottle neck is the printf() function call - build a new string up first and then print it after doing the checks - one printf() call per 4 byte check is an improvement. You can reduce the printf() calls more by only printing if at the end of result or every full line (console window).

Hope this helps, thanks - Neil